# Approximate 3D function that has certain points as peak

Tags: geometry, 3d, gaussian

Given set of 3D points, how can I find a continuous function that has each point as the peak?

You can imagine making a terrain editor that the inputs are 3D points and the output is a smooth mountain range that has each point as peak .

Comment: What  have you tried?

Comment: @user619894 Nothing yet

Comment: You might get more responses if you provide some context and your thoughts on the question.

Comment: @user619894 Thanks for the tip. I will elaborate next time. But this one I no longer need an answer so I’ll just leave it as it is.